# Azure DevOps YAML: compare two variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

To determine which parameter value (*my_param*) I want to pass to a template (*my-template.yml*), I would like to compare two variables (*var1* and *var2*) in my YAML pipeline.

```
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    ${{ if eq(variables.var1, variables.var2) }}:
      my_param: 'abc'
    ${{ else }}:
      my_param: 'xyz'
```

I tested this with different values for *var1* and *var2* (defined in a DevOps variable group/library). No matter what I put as variable values (whether or not they are equal), the "else" case is always triggered even if both variables have the same value. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe its a problem with how you are trying to access the variables?  An example from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#how-can-i-use-variables-inside-of-templates): `eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')` Also I have found that null variables might cause a problem. Null as in no value assigned? Maybe provide a bit more of your "code"...

Comment: The 2 variables are loaded from a variable group in DevOps, at the top of my YAML like this: variables: - group: 'My Variable Group'. Both variables exist in this group and are not null.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, there is no direct way to compare two variables in library->variable group.
So I suggest you set another variable 'compare' to previously compare the values of the two variables in the variable group.

Example:
In variablegroup 'MyVarGroup', I have var1 'SomeNumber' and var2 'samplevariable'. I now set var3 'compare', if var1=var2, I set var3 value '0', otherwise other different number.
You could also set it as true if the two variables are the same and false if they are different.

Here are my sample:

mytemplate.yml:

```
parameters:
  name: my_param
  type: string
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: echo "${{ parameters.my_param }}"][1]][1]
```

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
- group: MyVarGroup
- name: para
  value: $[replace(replace('True',eq(variables['compare'], '0'), 'abc'),'True','xyz')]
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script:  | 
           echo "$(SomeNumber)"
           echo "$(samplevariable)"
           echo "$(compare)"
           echo "$(para)"
- template: mytemplate.yml
  parameters:
      my_param: $(para)
```

If var3 compare is '0',then I will get 'abc' in the template output.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Otherwise, I will get 'xyz'
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I hope it could do some help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uYU6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeRy4.png

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using **Template Expression** Variables, which are processed at Compile time, most likely those variables are not available at compile time ‍♂️

> In a pipeline, template expression variables (${{ variables.var }})
> get processed at compile time, before runtime starts. Macro syntax
> variables ($(var)) get processed during runtime before a task runs.
> Runtime expressions ($[variables.var]) also get processed during
> runtime but are intended to be used with conditions and expressions.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

This table summarizes the differences:
[image]

You can try by using instead a runtime or a macro expression